# Generate JSON using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have 4 inputs in a form:

```
<form id="mark_date_form">
   <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" value="motherday">
   <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control datepick" placeholder="MM/DD" value="05/13">

   <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" value="fatherday">
   <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control datepick " placeholder="MM/DD" value="06/18">
</form>
```

When I use `$('#mark_date_form').serializeArray()` in jQuery, it returns

```
[
    {
        "name": "title",
        "value": "motherday"
    },
    {
        "name": "date",
        "value": "05/13"
    },
    {
        "name": "title",
        "value": "fatherday"
    },
    {
        "name": "date",
        "value": "06/18"
    }
]
```

**The question is I have to come out with something like this:**

```
[
    {
        "title": "motherday",
        "date": "05/13"
    },
    {
        "title": "fatherday",
        "date": "06/18"
    }
]
```

What should be the jQuery looks like?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var a = [];
$('#mark_date_form input').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('name')=='title'){
        a.push({"title":$(this).val(),"date":$(this).next().val()});
    }
});
console.log(a);
```

Output:

```
[Object { title="motherday",  date="05/13"}, Object { title="fatherday",  date="06/18"}]
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for this  `$("#mark_date_form").serialize()`;

**Update:** sorry for the @daniel-cai is correct. 
Use `$("#mark_date_form").serializeArray();` for getting JavaScript literal object.

Comment: great answer. +1, very fast.

Comment: Thank you for answer, this will return `title=motherday&date=05%2F13&title=fatherday&date=06%2F18`

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to get a json file as you want is:

```
var o = {};
$("#mark_date_form").serializeArray().map(function(x){o[x.name] = x.value;}); 
console.log(o);
```

Result:

```
Object {title: "motherday", date: "05/13"}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/gon250/s3xerkgc/1/

Hope it's helps.